# Natural homomorphism from local galois group to galois group of residue field extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, class-field-theory

Let $L/K$ be a galois extension of number field. Let $R_K$ and $R_L$ be ring of integers of $K$ and $L$.
Let $p$ be a unratified prime of $K$. Let $P$ be a unique prime above $p$.
There is map from $Gal(L_P/K_p)$ to $Gal((R_L/P)/(R_K/p))$.

I'm having trouble to prove this map is isomorphism.
I understand the proof of subjectivity, but stuck with injectivity. I should have to use the condition $p$ is uramified. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you shown injectivity or surjectivity?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that. Subjectivity is ok for me, I'm stuck proving infectivity.

Comment: Hensel lemma, $L_P = K_p(\zeta_{p^f-1}), R_L/P = R_K/p(\zeta_{p^f-1})$.

Comment: Could you tell me why $L_P/K_p$ is unramified when $p$ is unramified?